# iPhone: How to prevent App (or UIWebView) from accessing the network/web

Tags: iphone, networking, uiwebview, connection

one of the viewControllers in my iPhone App has a UIWebView. Whenever this viewController gets loaded, I would like to prevent my App from being able to access the web (regardless if an actual connection is available or not).

Background:
What I am trying to do, is to ensure, that users with a limited data plan won't be "risking" to go beyond their limited when working with my App.

My App loads user specific html pages into a UIWebView. This particular viewController is kind of a preview - but it should not have web access.

So I either would like to prevent the UIWebView from accessing the web or be able to turn on/off web access for my entire App.

Any "App-store-save" ideas or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you and
Best Regards,
Ralph

**Edited on March 1st 2011:**
Included more info:

It appears that the answer below from hotpaw2 (= using shouldStartWithLoadRequest) does unfortunately not provide a solution.

To give an example, I tested it by loading the follwing html into the UIWebView. The BaseURL is set correctly so that the local files can be accessed. As expected, shouldStartLoadWithRequest gets only called once for the initial load of the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test example</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="image-On-Device.jpg" alt=""><br>
<img src="http://www.aWebsite.xx/anOnlineImage.jpg" alt=""><br>
<img src="image-On-Device.jpg" alt=""><br>
<img src="http://www.aWebsite.xx/anOnlineImage.jpg" alt=""><br>
</body>
</html>
```

This example will cause the device to access the web to fetch: "anOnlineImage.jpg".
Note: images are only one example of resources that might be requested online.
Hence, how can I prevent any type of webaccess - without having to modify the entire html?

Answer (score 1):

Use the UIWebView webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: delegate to inspect and return NO for any UIWebView attempts to access URLs other than those on your permitted list.

Comment: I'm not sure this works. I do want to load the user specific html into the UIWebView. However in case the custom html has an src set to a resource on the web (e.g. src to an image on the web instead of local on the device) I want to prevent this src to be loaded. I don't think shouldStartLoadWithRequest gets fired for this.